# ConcatMap interupted when error in one observable

Tags: rxjs, observable, concatmap

I have the following code:

```
Observable.from(modifiedNodes)
    .concatMap(node => {
        return this.Model.setData(node);
    })
    .subscribe(() => {
        NodeSaved++;
    }
```

If `setData` throws an error for any intermediate node, the next sequence of nodes are not getting resumed. How we can modify it so that even if there is an error for one node, the next sequence of nodes will be executed? I read about `onErrorResumeNext` but I'm not sure how to use it here.

The method signature for `setData` is as follows:

```
public setData(node: INode): Observable<Object>{}
```

Comment: The answer will depend upon what `setData` returns, so you should include at least its signature in the question.

Comment: @cartant I added the signature of setdata(). thanks for your reply

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If `setData` returns an observable, you can use the `catch` operator. It will receive any errors thrown from within `setData` and if you return an empty observable, `concatMap` will move to the next node in the sequence:

```js
import 'rxjs/add/observable/empty';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';

Observable
  .from(modifiedNodes)
  .concatMap(node => this.Model
    .setData(node)
    .catch(error => Observable.empty())
  )
  .subscribe(() => { NodeSaved++; });
```

Comment: thanks for the help. the only thing is I couldn't find empty() method for observable instead I used Observable.of() which worked for me.

Comment: Added the import for `empty`, too.